# Получить дистанцию каждого GeoObject из GeoObjectCollection

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Я поочередно GeoObject добавляю в GeoObjectCollection 
Как мне получить дистанцию всех объектов в коллекции? как вернуть массив всех геообектов в коллекции, в документации есть метод getAll(), но я не знаю как им пользоваться

```
    var lineString = new ymaps.geometry.LineString(lines);
    var geoObject = new ymaps.GeoObject({ geometry: lineString });
    polylineCollection.add(geoObject);
    myMap.geoObjects.add(polylineCollection);
    // console.log(geoObject.geometry.getDistance());
```

Answer (score 1):

[GeoObjectCollection.toArray](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/GeoObjectCollection-docpage/#method_detail__toArray)

```
polylineCollection.toArray()
```